# MessageBox from daemon in Swift (OS X)

Tags: macos, swift, daemon

I'm new to Swift (and programming for OS X). I'm trying to get a simple notification pop-up from a daemon.
In Windows I could use MessageBox.Show("Some text") for this, but with Swift I'm struggling. If I try to use NSAlert like this

```
    let alert:NSAlert = NSAlert();
    alert.messageText = "Message";
    alert.informativeText = "Info";
    alert.runModal();
```

it won't show, program seems to hang.

CFUserNotification should be another way, but I cannot seem to find how to use this properly.

Comment: For me it works perfectly fine at Xcode 6.3.

Comment: I'm also using Xcode 6.3. Are you sure you tried this with a command line tool (not a cocao application)?